# Exercise 1.2.11 in Tao's "Hilbert's Fifth Problem"

Tags: group-theory, asymptotics

I am reading Tao's book "Hilbert's fifth problem" (freely available online https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/hilbert-book.pdf) and I'm trying to do most exercises. I have little experience with calculations involving asymptotics, hence I want to ask if the following solution is correct. The exercise I'm trying to solve is 1.2.11 (ii):
Let $V$ be a $C^{1,1}$ local group. Show that
$$x*y*x^{*-1}*y^{*-1} = O(|x||y|),$$
for $x,y$ sufficiently close to the identity.

I recall the definition of a $C^{1,1}$ local group.

**Definition:** A $C^{1,1}$ local group is a local group $V$ which is a neighbourhood of the identity $0$ in a Euclidean space with group identity $0$, whose operation $*$ obeys
$$x*y = x+y +O(|x||y|),$$
for $x,y$ sufficiently close to the identity.

**My solution**

We follow the hint and start by proving $x*y = y* x + O(|x||y|).$ Indeed,
\begin{align*}
    |x*y| &\leq |x+y| + C|x||y| \\
    &\leq |y*x|  + C|x||y| + C|x||y|\\
    &\leq |y*x|  + C|x||y|.
\end{align*}
Now we calculate
\begin{align*}
    x*y &= (x*y*x^{*-1}*y^{*-1}) * (y *x) \\
    &\stackrel{?}{=}(x*y*x^{*-1}*y^{*-1}) * (x *y) + O(|x||y|) \\
    &= x*y*x^{*-1}*y^{*-1} + x *y + O(|x||y|) + O(|x*y*x^{*-1}*y^{*-1}||x*y|).
\end{align*}
Thus
\begin{align*}
    0 &= x*y*x^{*-1}*y^{*-1} + O(|x||y|) + O(|x*y*x^{*-1}*y^{*-1}||x*y|) \\
    &= x*y*x^{*-1}*y^{*-1} + O(|x||y|),
\end{align*}
for $x,y$ sufficiently close to the origin.

**Question**

Is this solution valid? I'm particularly worried about the equality indicated with a question mark.

Comment: There are multiple problems here. First, your demonstration that $x * y = y * x + O(|x||y|)$ is wrong. This statement is semantically equivalent to $|x*y-y*x| = O(|x||y|)$, whereas you have proved only $|x*y| \le |y*x| +O(|x||y|)$. Second, the equality you mark as dubious as well as a few further steps are poorly justified. This exercise is a bit subtle and you must be careful with the hypotheses.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thanks for the reply. I can fix the demonstration of $x*y = y* x + O(|x||y|)$ by simply inverting the roles of $x$ and $y$ (or also by using the reverse triangle inequality). However, I am not sure how to justify the later steps.

Comment: Go ahead and fix what you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Tao's hint, let $z = x*y*x^{*-1}*y^{*-1}$. Then, for $x, y$ near $0$,
$$x*y = z * y * x = z + y*x + O(|z|\,|y*x|).$$
Both $x*y$ and $y*x$ are $x+y+O(|x|\,|y|)$, and $|y*x| = O(|x|+|y|)$, so it follows that
$$z = O(|x|\,|y| + |x|\,|z| + |y|\,|z|).$$
In other words there are constants $\delta>0$ and $C$ such that whenever $|x|,|y| < \delta$ we have
$$|z| \le C(|x|\,|y| + |x|\,|z| + |y|\,|z|).$$
Let $\delta' = \min(\delta, 1/(4C))$. Then for $|x|, |y| < \delta' \le 1/(4C)$ we have $C (|x|\,|z|+|y|\,|z|) \le |z|/2$, so the inequality above implies $|z| \le 2C|x|\,|y|$, i.e., $|z| = O(|x|\,|y|)$.

Comment: This is precisely the example of working with asymptotics that I was looking for. Thank you :)